# TextInputLayout is not working when I set OutlinedBox in style

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

Working on layout added dependencies `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`
after also it is not working

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextCode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="6"
                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"
                android:gravity="start"
                />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>`
```

Comment: Use `TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText` but what does it mean "it is not working" ?

Comment: that too tried still not working

Comment: Provide more details pls. What does it mean:"it is not working"?

Comment: First, read the [official docx](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/) properly. You're using `EditText` instead of `TextInputEditText`, also when using `TextInputLayout`, properties like `drawableLeft` comes under `TextInputLayout` tag. You should read the official documentations.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Got solution actually problem in style 

<style name="AppTheme" parent="**Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar**">

//Changed parent theme to MaterialComponents its working well for me.
```

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me in API 33

Answer (score 0):

use TextInputEditText insted of EditText. Check the below code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutName"          
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEditTextName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text="Data" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but actually problem is in style

Answer (score 0):

Use the **`startIconDrawable`** attribute to define an icon and use the `TextInputEditText` instead of the `EditText`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        ..>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Noteing this here if someone else does the same misstake I did.

The `android:Background` attribute can hide the outline of the given style if used in the sub-element.

Add the background to the TextInputLayout element and not the TextInputEditText.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:id="@+id/txtNewTextLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtNewTitleLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtNewText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```